# How to iterate name of output image name in blender via python?

Tags: python

For example I want it to be something like:
RenderedImage1.png
RenderedImage2.png
and etc
How to do something like this?

Here's the code I have:

```
import bpy
from random import randint
from random import random
from random import uniform

ob = bpy.context.active_object

ob.particle_systems[-1].settings.hair_step = randint(0, 20)
ob.particle_systems[-1].settings.hair_step = randint(0, 20)

def render_image():
    if  bpy.context.scene.frame_current == 250:
        bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = 'BlenderRepository/RenderedImages/RenderedImage.png'
        bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_x = 1920
        bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_y = 1080
        bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)

render_image()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call [`RenderSettings.frame_path()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.RenderSettings.html#bpy.types.RenderSettings.frame_path) which returns the *absolute path to the filename for a given frame* **or** [concatenate your string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169839/which-is-the-preferred-way-to-concatenate-a-string-in-python) like  `".../folder/image_" + str(250) + ".jpg"`(error prone due to OS differences).

Proof using the Console:

```
>>> rd = C.scene.render
>>> rd.frame_path(frame=250)
'/tmp/0250.png'
```

---

For multiple render iterations, I'd suggest append the iterator to the filepath:

```
C = bpy.context
rd = C.scene.render

for r in range(1,3):
    path, ext = rd.frame_path(frame=250).rsplit('.', 1)
    multi_path = path + "_" + str(r) + "." + ext
    print (multi_path)
```

Terminal Output:

```
/tmp/0250_1.png
/tmp/0250_2.png
```

Comment: The 250th frame is the frame I need, I cannot change it. I want to exe my script and get RenderedImage1.png. Then again I execute it once more and now i get RenderedImage2.png

Comment: You don't have to *change* it, you just need to pass the integer to the function. Take your time and think about that @cxnt

Comment: For whatever reason your comment changed... You want to have `RenderedImage1.png` instead of `RenderedImage_0250.png`? Why? @cxnt

Comment: Because it looks better @brockmann