# Is there any way to iterate the name of output image file?

Tags: python, scripting, command-line

This is the command that I'm putting into console:

```
cd /home/ds/Documents/blender2.80/
./blender --background filename.blend --python myscript.py --python myscript2.py -o //BlenderRepository/Images/ -f 250
```

And on the output I'm getting a 0250.png file

So I want to get 0001.png file once I put my command in console. Then I'm closing console, and re-open it again and put the same command and get 0002.png

Is there anyway to achieve that? via console command or python

Comment: How this question is different from: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146442/how-to-iterate-name-of-output-image-name-in-blender-via-python ? Take your time and explain in detail what you'd like to have or **edit your question** instead.

Comment: I want to know if that's possible via console @brockmann

Comment: Why not? It's the same... @cxnt

Comment: I simply want to know if that's possible, and if it is possible, I want to know how to @brockmann

Comment: @rjg I've never worked with python or blender before

Comment: @brockmann You'd have to iterate through the entire directory and find the highest number. Not sure if that is a good solution.

Comment: @brockmann yes obviously it works. The question is if it's a good idea. The currently described approach sounds far more complicated than it should it be. A single script could generate the scene and render the frames, without manually having to run the command for every single frame.

Comment: Can I get the answer if that's possible via console, not python? @rjg

Comment: Can I get the answer if that's possible via console, not python? @brockmann

Comment: @cxnt No, not purely in command line. The two thing you could do is either have a script that that setups up a scene where you have the hairstyles changing every frame and then render this as animation from console or you have a script that setups one frame of the scene, renders, changes the scene (in a loop for a given limit). In the latter case the command line doesn't trigger the rendering, the script would with a changed name on every loop iteration.

Comment: @rjg sounds like a good idea, but I don't know how to make it

Comment: @cxnt what particular part?

Comment: almost every part tbh @rjg

Comment: @cxnt Unfortunately we can't teach you python programming, that is something you have to do on your own. The python API for Blender 2.8 is documented here: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/. If you have specific questions, you can ask them on here, otherwise https://blenderartists.org/ will be more suitable.

Comment: bash: `mv render_0250.jpg render_0250_1.jpg` @cxnt

Comment: @brockmann That would be the third way. Add another layer of scripting by automating the command line via bash (or another python script with subprocess). Given the current level of experience I think that wouldn't really help though.